# Как создать элемент на пустой странице на js

Tags: javascript

Для примера, есть пустая страница на ***`html`***, кроме тега ***`script`*** на ней ничего нет. Подскажите как создать на ней блок или абзац. Только ***`vanilla`*** пожалуйста.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document

Answer (score 2):

```js
// var YourVarriableName = document.createElement("ElementWhatYouNeed");
// YourVarriableName.textContent = "YourSomeTextForTheElement";
// document.body.appendChild(YourVarriableName);

var block = document.createElement("div");
block.textContent = "Блок";
document.body.appendChild(block);

var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
paragraph.textContent = "Параграф";
document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
```

Answer (score 2):

Для создания элементов можно воспользоваться методом [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

Данный метод принимаем имя элемента, который нужно создать и возвращает созданный элемент.

Для того, чтобы элемент отобразился на странице, его нужно добавить в один из элементов, которые уже есть. Например в элемент `body`.

Добавить можно с помощью метода [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Пример:

```js
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Альтернативным вариантом может стать вставка html строки, с помощью свойства [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), либо метода [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `<p class="d">1</p>`;

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="d2">2</div>`);
```

```css
.d {
  background-color: green;
}

.d2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```